# meteor client side access to an existing mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am new to Meteorjs and I am trying to retrieve data from an already existing MongoDB.
Heres what I have so far:

1. I set the env variable MONGO_URL to the mongoDB url
   export MONGO_URL="mongodb://username:password@address:port/dbname"
2. Created a new meteor project with the following code:

   ```
   MyCollection = new Meteor.Collection('mycollection');

   if (Meteor.isClient) {
       //Meteor.subscribe("mycollection");
       console.log(MyCollection.findOne());
       Template.hello.greeting = function () {
           return MyCollection.findOne();
       };
   }

   if (Meteor.isServer) {
       Meteor.startup(function () {
           // code to run on server at startup
           console.log(MyCollection.findOne());
       }); 
   }
   ```

I know the server side `console.log(MyCollection.findOne());` works as it prints out the correct data on the terminal.

The problem is with the client side. When I view the page on my browser, the data is blank and `console.log(MyCollection.findOne());` shows 'undefined'.

I know that autopublish is on and I dont have to manually publish the collection from the server side.

I would like to know how I could make the client read from my external mongoDB directly.
Let me know if you have any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even with autopublish on, there is a lag between the client starting and the data being published. At the time that your first `console.log` is run, the documents haven't finished syncing so the `findOne` will return `undefined`. It turns out this isn't a big deal; as you get more familiar with meteor, you will see that the results of `find` operations are often used in non time-sensitive ways. An easy way to check if the client has the data is just to wait for the page to load, then start the browser console, and manually type:

```
console.log(MyCollection.findOne());
```

As for your other problem, the greeting needs to be something that can be displayed in html - a string for example. It can't be a document. Assuming your document had a `message` property you could do:

```
return MyCollection.findOne().message;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I didn't know that it takes a while for the data to get published.

This led me on the right track and I discovered that the reason it was taking so long was because the db was too big. I tested it on a smaller db and it seems to work.

Comment: I'm glad that was helpful. Hopefully you can determine a way to publish a smaller subset of the data and improve performance.