# Meteor - difference Client and Server side when accessing remote database

Tags: meteor, minimongo

Hi Meteor newbie here.

As I am prototyping an app, I get issues accessing a remote database on the client side of my app. More specifically, I run meteor `MONGO_URL="mongodb://__id__:__pwd__@__address__.mlab.com:21010/meteor" meteor`

and have in a public folder the following :

`Collection = new Mongo.Collection("collection");
console.log(Collection.find().count());`

which yields the correct number in the meteor shell and 0 in my browser. Now I have seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21506782/meteor-client-side-access-to-an-existing-mongodb) that the cause might a

> lag between the client starting and the data being published

However, when I try `console.log(Collection.find().count())` in my browser console, I get that same 0.

For the record, I have left `autopublish` and `insecure` untouched.

Would be glad to here any recommendations!

Comment: That should work just fine in browser console, if you have autopublish enabled. By "server console" you mean "meteor shell", not the mongo shell, right?

Comment: Weird indeed. Sorry for the imprecision, I do mean meteor shell. I also tried to connect to a local mongo database with the same method and sadly the same results.

Comment: if you are using the database of another Meteor application, you can use `DDP.connect`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bash file like this. If you don't have any setting.json file please remove that from the last line.

```
#!/bin/bash
: # This shell script runs on both Windows CMD and Bash. The system-specific sections are marked by
: # comments, and share the final invocation of meteor

:<<"::CMDLITERAL"

@ECHO OFF
REM This is the CMD section
ECHO Running in CMD mode
SET export MONGO_URL= mongodb://__id__:__pwd__@__address__.mlab.com:21010/meteor
SET DEV_ENV=development
GOTO :COMMON
::CMDLITERAL

# This is the Bash section
echo Running in Bash mode
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://__id__:__pwd__@__address__.mlab.com:21010/meteor
export DEV_ENV="development"


:<<"::CMDLABEL"
:COMMON
::CMDLABEL

meteor run --settings settings.json --port 4000
```

You can also directly run using comment like 
In liunx

```
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://__id__:__pwd__@__address__.mlab.com:21010/meteor
meteor
```

In windows

```
SET export MONGO_URL= mongodb://__id__:__pwd__@__address__.mlab.com:21010/meteor
meteor
```

As per you current problem you are missing SET or export while setting mongo url.